# Grouping vertical rows to horizontal rows

Tags: php, mysql

problem in getting vertical rows to horizontal rows

```
SELECT 
rate.`customer_rate_id`,
rate.`customer_name`,
rate.`destination_name`,
del.`wh_storage_location_name`,
(CASE WHEN rate.destination_name=1 THEN 'zone a' ELSE 'zone s' END) ZONE_A,
(CASE WHEN rate.destination_name=2 THEN 'zone b' ELSE 'zone d' END) ZONE_B
FROM `m_ac_customer_rate` rate
LEFT JOIN m_point_delivery_location del ON del.`wh_storage_location_id`=rate.`destination_name`
WHERE
`customer_name`=7
GROUP BY rate.`destination_name`
```

i getting result as

```
zone_name    weight   rate
zone A       1.5 kg   100 Rs
zone B        2 kg    150 R
```

s

but i want

```
weight   zone A   zone B
 1.5 kg  100 Rs , 150 Rs
 2 kg    150 Rs , 200 Rs
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output as text in the question would be nice.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.